# How can I get text/string information from a website and put it into a text document, in C# or Java?

Tags: java, c#, web, text-files

I'm trying to get text from a website and then save it into a text document. Not sure what is the syntax to do so? Of getting info from a website, and then putting it into a text document.

Comment: @you should try searching the internet there ton of resources for this question just search "scrape html using C#" and apply regex or something simalr

Comment: It would involve (1) reading HTML code of your page, (2) parsing it, (3) getting data you want, (4) saving it into your text file. Each of these steps has already been explained on Stack Overflow. Try to find similar questions and come back when your code will not work.

Comment: step (0) some basic effort

Comment: Just a little bit of googling should have done your job.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code :

```
StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("linkToYourPage.html"));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            content.append(str);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
String contentText = content.toString();
```